# Stop gnu screen from asking for a password on screen -rd

Tags: gnu-screen

Looks like GNU screen considers detach a lock request, and always locks when detached. How do I disable this? I trust all users (myself) on the box, and care little about the security implications.

Comment: You can check my answer here to disable this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768248/111873